# Flash messages are not displayed after redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After setting a flash message like this:

```
flash[:notice] = "Invalid Username or Password"
format.html { redirect_to :action => :log}
```

the redirect happens, but the flash message is not displayed

Comment: The flash shows up when there's no redirect?

Comment: Displaying the flash message doesn't happen automagically. Show us the template of the page you're redirecting to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `flash[:notice]` in the redirect method:

```
format.html { redirect_to :action => :log, notice: "Invalid Username or Password}
```

Comment: That's equivalent. The problem is likely that the flash message is set in the controller but not displayed in the view.